Amending the "closed as duplicate" message?
Currently, the closed-as-duplicate message states:

This question already has answers here:

followed by a link to the duplicated question(s).
However, it happens that someone who asked the question is not satisfied with the existing question/answers – sometimes for legitimate reasons that were unfortunately not clarified by the person who asked. In this case, ideally, the person who asked the question should edit it to show how the existing question/answers do not address their specific problem.
However, the message is very short and does not mention the possibility to edit the question for it to be reopened. It does not even link to the help page about duplicates. If I were a new user, in particular someone unfamiliar with Stack Exchange websites, I might incorrectly think that this message is a definitive refusal to address my problem, with no recourse.
I'd suggest to amend the current message, with a statement adapted from the help page:

This question already has answers here:
<here goes the link>
If you don't agree that it
truly is a duplicate, edit the question to highlight the differences, then try
to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote.

(I'm not entirely sure if we should mention "then try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote", but you get the idea).
I have two questions:

Should we amend the current message at all?
If so, do you have other, better suggestions than the one above?


+1 Thank you for posting this.  I have just checked the page for modifying the close message.  It looks like the message for closed-as-duplicate cannot be modified by us, indicating your proposal would need to be escalated system wide.  The three we can change (and which have been established for years following discussion here) are "Self-study questions", "Programming or data request", and "Not on topic."

@whuber Thanks for looking into it. I assume I shall post a new question about it on https://meta.stackexchange.com, unless there is another channel I'm unaware of for this kind of request. However, I'll wait a bit before escalating it, to see if some people in the CV community have objections to such a change.

@J-J-J I can see no objections to proposals which would enhance clarity re possible further actions that OP might take to clarify their query. As I see, this seems to be not on the purview of site mods but rather warrants a SE supervision.

Possibly the message the O.P. sees is different to the message the rest of us see - I'll try & find out

According to this post by a staff member, the O.P. does get advised to edit their post.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks! If it's indeed the case, this is great and I think it should settle the issue.

As far as I can tell, the only users who can verify this are those who have one of their own questions closed as a duplicate. I haven't, but fortunately a moderator from another site has, & kindly posted a screenshot confirming that the text is as described in the post I linked to above.

I would not include, "then try...", but this is a good idea, even if superseded by the information the OP sees that we do not.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica, perhaps you could turn your comment as an answer for it seems this very much responds properly to the query (of course, if you wish).

If this discussion gets anytime further, then I would suggest to make the notice sound more friendly. Instead of

If you don't agree that it truly is a duplicate, edit the question to highlight the differences, then try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote.

I would suggest to eliminate phrases like ”if you don't agree" end "then try to get it reopened". These sound a bit aggressive.
Possibly something less combative could be chosen instead

Your question could be different and might still be worthwhile but may need an update. Try to edit the question to highlight the differences with the duplicates.


Sidenote, this is how the message of a duplicate looks on Cross Validated to the person that created the post

